# would + verb construction

Tags: grammar

I've been learning english for some time now, but have a hugh problems with all constructions with 'would'. For example today I found that out in one of the NYT articles:

[...]**He wouldn’t learn anything.** He was making no effort to learn.[...]

or another example:
Reporter asks: **So what conversations would you two have?**

Could you huys help me to understand what construction is this? Is this something like reported speach or one of the conditionals? How to think about it?

Many thanks, Lukasz, from Poland

Comment: 'He wouldn't do X' in this sense means 'He was stubborn; he refused to do X'. // 'So what conversations would you two have' possibly here means something along the lines of 'If it ever happened that you were stranded together on a desert island, what conversations would you two have?' (ie a hypothetical situation) but probably deals with a habitual real past occurrence: 'So, you two were often in the locomotive cab together. What conversations would you have (what things would you usually talk about in those times  when you were in the cab together'?

Answer (score 0):

*would* in this sense is an idiomatic way of speaking about past habits.

To talk about past habits we mostly use **2** constructs.

1- **used to** - with a simple past declarative clause with a to-infinitive clause as a direct object .

e.g.

He *used to* clean the dishes after him. Now, all he does is leave a mess behind.

A past habitual action that no longer happens.

2- **would** - with an infinitive verb

e.g

We *would* look at each other all day when we were left alone.

Again a past habitual action, but unlike *used to*, can still happen today.

Two big differences though, as they seem interchangeable.

the fist:

'Used to' can be used to talk about past states as well as past repeated actions and habits, but 'would' is only used to talk about past habits. 'Would' is not used to talk about past states.

The second (as with your example)

*Used to* doesn't work well in a negation clause whereas *would* does.

Answer (score 0):

Would is used in these ways:

**Past tense of will**

My grandfather was a very fit man - every day he would go jogging. - Past habit (Used to).

He said he would do it tomorrow. - Reported speech. (Past tense of will.)

I wonder how tired those people would be" Reported speech and an indirect question. The direct question is “I wondered, ‘How tired will those people be?’.”

He wouldn't help me. - Refusal in the past.

“If I asked him, he would not help me.” (See conditional below.)

I would say that he is about 30 years old. – Softening, or expressing some uncertainty about, an opinion. (Also See hidden conditional "If I had to decide, I would say that he is about 30 years old.")

One day he would become president. - Future in the past.

**Subjunctive:**
I wish he would stop doing that. – Pseudo-subjunctive. Regret about somebody's [current] behaviour or habits.

**Third conditional**

If he had heard the weather forecast, he would have started earlier. - Third conditional expressing a high probability.

Would you like to have more coffee? – (i) Polite offer (ii) Part of a hidden third conditional = If I were to ask you, would you like to have more coffee?

Would you help me with this? (i) Indirect question (ii) part of a hidden third conditional = If I were to ask you, would you help me with this? (iii) Softening a request/a polite request.

**Probability or Possibility**

Be careful! It would break if you dropped it. - Predicting a high probability.
Well, he would say that, wouldn't he? - Commenting on the high probability (of his saying that) based upon his typical/habitual behaviour.

**The past tense of the full verb “to will”**

I would rather you didn't do that. Past tense of the full verb “to will” (= {(to wish or want) + rather (adverb = preferably)} = Expressing a preferential wish about an action

Compare the subjunctive use in Byron’s poem: “I would I were a careless child, Still dwelling in my Highland cave,”